# Can a fake window glass exist?

Tags: optics, reflection

A standard window glass shows exactly what is on the other side of the glass. If the watcher changes the angle or the position of their eye, the image they see changes.

I know there is a tool which lets you create a similar effect, but without actually putting anything on the other side of the glass. It's called mirror. You look at it and you see an image. The image changes if you change your position or your angle.

A standard mirror is very limited - it can only show (reflect) what's in front of it.

**The question(s):**

Is it possible to modify the mirror so that it shows an image of my choice? In other words, is it possible to create an effect of a standard window glass, but without actually placing anything on the other side of the glass?

Is it proven either that it is possible or that it's not possible?

If it possible to create such construction, has it been constructed? How is it called?

I think it's obvious, but I'll add it anyway: I'm asking about if it's possible without any use of VR, high-tech solutions, without computer, hopefully without any electronics at all.

Comment: [Lenticular printing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenticular_printing) (e.g. in motion cards) is one way to do something similar, to a limited extent.

Comment: You want a mirror, but instead of reflecting what's in the room, you want it to show you a chosen image. So a painting? You make a painting of what you want people to see when they look in the "mirror."

Comment: @AndrewChristensen If I understand correctly, the intention is to have the image move when you do, as if you are looking out a window.

Comment: You could doubtless rig something up with a video camera, a flat panel display and motion sensors.  However I voted to close as this questions seems like engineering to me.

Comment: How about some kind of hologram?

Comment: @PM2Ring, The literal meaning of the word, "hologram," describes exactly what the OP is asking for. It means a "picture" that captures a _whole_ scene (as opposed to a normal photograph, which only captures what was seen from a single point of view.) A classic laser hologram comes pretty close to what the OP asked for. If it's well made, and well presented, then viewing the hologram is exactly like looking through a window at the scene... assuming that the scene was lit by a monochromatic light source. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holography#/media/File:Holomouse2.jpg

Comment: @SolomonSlow Indeed! That's why I suggested it. And using metamaterials and 3 lasers you can even make trichromatic holograms https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.nanolett.9b04107# but that might be too high-tech for the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very old way to get part of what you want.

Behind the window, put another window glass at a 45 degree angle.

Arrange lights so that the area on either side of the diagonal glass can be brightly lit or dark.

Whichever side is light, that side will be visible through the window. If there's a picture of a beautiful woman directly behind the glass, she can show up. But if her side is dark, and there's a picture of a gorrilla at a 90 degree angle sideways, when the gorrilla's side is lit up that image will be reflected from the diagonal glass and that's what you'll see.

You asked for nothing on the other side of the glass, and with this we have a space behind the glass that's likely bigger than the glass itself. If you redefine the window as being thicker than that space, then it sort of fits what you want, but not really.